# Check if an object is in a sorted list

Tags: python, list, sorting

What's the easiest way to check weather an object is in a sorted list?
I have found bisect, but that only finds the insertion points.
Sure this index could then be used to check if the object exists in the list.
But is there a easier way?

Something similar to the "in" command? Returning a True/False but for sorted lists?

Comment: Think about it, if `bisect` lets you find the insertion point, how you could check if the value is in the list at that point..

Comment: if the index belongs to the list, that is.

Comment: So I need to do something like, L[bisect(L,n)-1] == n ?

Comment: @Johan: use `bisect_left()`, and you don't have to subtract. You'll have to account for the possibility that the resulting index is 1 higher than the last valid index. So use `idx = bisect_left(L, n)` and then use `idx < len(L) and L[idx] == n`.